# iOS user info at first launch

Tags: ios

How do I collect user info the first time my app launches?

I want to make sure they agree to terms of use - if they disagree, how do I keep them from using app features?

Comment: Like name, age, eye color. etc. Mainly just need to confirm the user agreement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question; simplest possible way; just check NSUserDefaults if the information you require is saved there.

If it is, great, just start the app.

If it's not, ask the user to enter the information and accept the agreement. When that's done, save it in NSUserDefaults so the next time it won't ask, and start the app.

If the user never agrees, the info is not in NSUserDefaults, so he won't be able to get past the accept screen, it'll ask him to accept every time.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you elaborate?